# Python: How to know if a value was put in super’s attribute or was it put in a dynamically-created self attribute?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties, attributes

For troubleshooting and learning: What command will show me if my value was put in Machine.manufacturer or if Python dynamically created a Printer.manufacturer?

Is there a way to answer that with info shown in PyCharm?

(I want the value stored in Machine.manufacturer. I don’t want dynamically created manufacturer attributes in Printer and all its siblings)

```
class Machine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manufacturer = None
class Printer(Machine):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Machine.__init__(self)
        self.manufacturer = kwargs.get("manufacturer")
p1 = Printer(manufacturer = "ABC Company")
print(f'{p1.manufacturer}. Is this value from Machine or Printer?.')
```

Comment: All attributes like `manufacturer` are dynamically created. Once you have created an instance of `Printer`, then the original *'location'* of such attributes are lost since `Printer` will dynamically inherit them.

Comment: there is no method to check it. Maybe if you create @property which use other variable to inform when value was assigned then you could check it. Or  `machine would have to set it manually  `self.created_in_machine = True` and `Printer` would set `self.created_in_machine = False`